# Weird behavior of searchbar: keyboard getting dismissed after typing first letter

Tags: iphone, keyboard, uisearchbar

After typing first letter in search bar keyboard getting dismissed .

Not understanding why it is happning. Already used searchbar so many times.

I have used

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
```

and

```
-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)sBar
```

these delegate methods.

Nothing else done with resigning keyboard but still after typing first letter in searchbar keyboard getting dismissed.

Please any one gone through same issue/ have any clue help me.

here is code

```
 -(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
   {    
       if([searchText length]>0)
    {  //searching code goes here

    }
  else  if ([searchText length]==0)
   { 
          // code to reload table
       }

  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the code in the function - (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText

Comment: You must be adding searchBar in section header, try adding it on the tableview Header. It will work.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, I tested with empty 'textDidChange' function and searchBar is assigned as tableHeaderView but it still happens. Help!