# Keyboard gets dismissed after one character is typed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I've added a `UISearchDisplayController` to the first cell of my `UITableView` in the `Storyboard` and set up the proper delegate callbacks.  Everything works fine except one annoying behavior -- the keyboard gets dismissed after the first character is typed.  After the keyboard gets dismissed, I have to touch the UISearchBar again to bring up the keyboard and enter the second and subsequent characters.

There's an SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804106/weird-behavior-of-searchbar-keyboard-getting-dismissed-after-typing-first-lette) with similar problem and the solution given was (per @Hisenberg) that not to add the `UISearchDisplayController` to the section.  This does not help me because I am not adding the search bar to the section of the tableview.

Has anyone seen similar behavior?

UPDATED:  Per @Logan comment, moving the search bar out of the tableview was the solution this problem.

[image]
If I type in a letter here, the keyboard gets dismissed.

[image]

Comment: Without seeing what you do with the various `UISearchBarDelegate` and `UISearchDisplayDelegate` methods, it's impossible to help you.

Comment: You said you added the search display to the first cell of your table view, are you calling reloadData on your table view when the user starts typing?  I can't say for sure, but it seems like it is bad design to include the search display as a cell in the same table where you want to display the results of said search.

Comment: @Logan.  It was indeed bad design and the root cause of the unwanted behavior.  I moved the search display out of the tableview and all is good.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad you got it working!

Comment: I am facing the same problem. @Loozie how did you moved search bar off tableView? Didi you assign tableHeaderView or did something else?

Comment: @fnc12.  I moved search bar out of the tableview.

Answer (score 0):

***UISearchDisplayController*** manages the search functionality for you, but you'd still need to play some roles, as this fragment from Apple Docs explains:

"*In addition to managing the searchable data, the original view controller typically plays four more roles you need to fill when using a search display controller. Those roles are the following:*

*Data source for the search results table view (searchResultsDataSource), which provides the data for the results table.
Delegate for the search results table view (searchResultsDelegate), which responds to the user’s selection of an item in the results table.
Delegate for the search display controller (delegate), which responds to events such the starting or ending of a search, and the showing or hiding of the search interface.
As a convenience, this delegate may also be told about changes to the search string or search scope, so that the results table view can be reloaded.
Delegate for the search bar (delegate described in UISearchBar Class Reference), which responds to changes in search criteria.*"[UISearchDisplayController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISearchDisplayController/searchResultsDataSource)

Please, could you check how are you responding as a **UISearchBarDelegate**?.
If you would like to launch searches and dismiss keyboard only after pressing search button for example, you'd be implementing for example the following method:

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
```

If you'd like to reload results of searching, and dismiss the keyboard only after 3 letters have been entered, you'd implement the following method from [UISearchDisplayDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchDisplayDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UISearchDisplayDelegate/searchDisplayController%3ashouldReloadTableForSearchString%3a):

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
```